# Change specific line in a file while transfering using SSH

Tags: ssh

I'm deploying my project to production server using `scp` command. As part of the deployment process I upload to server the `.htaccess` file. Locally, the environment is set to `DEVELOPMENT`:

```
#Set environment
#[PRODUCTION, STAGING, TESTING, DEVELOPMENT] 

SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'DEVELOPMENT'
```

However, when uploaded to server it needs to be changed to `PRODUCTION`. Is there any way I can accomplish that with ssh?

Comment: Why can't you change the file locally and then copy it?

Comment: I don't mind changing it locally as long as it is done automatically by script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a `sed` command and the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i "s/SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'DEVELOPMENT'/SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'PRODUCTION'/g" /path/to/.htaccess
```

Via `ssh` I would look like this:

```
ssh user@host "sed -i \"s/SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'DEVELOPMENT'/SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'PRODUCTION'/g\" /path/to/.htaccess"
```

Working with `sed` to replace strings in files is quite simple:

```
sed -i 's/search_string/replace_string/g' file
```

Replaces all occurences of `search_string` with `replace_string` of the gives `file`. `-i` causes `sed` to edit the file in place, instead of writing to standard output (stdout).

If you only want the first occurence to be replace use this sed command:

```
sed -i '0,/search_string/s/search_string/replace_string/' file
```

For more information about `sed` use `man sed`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I assume this command will replace all instances in the file, correct? Although it works for me know, can you please provide example of replacing text on a particular? It seems that it is possible based on the description of the `sed` command, however, I can't figure out how I can do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Maximus yes it replaces all instances, see my edit for replacing strings in file in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly write to the file locally as follows:

```
echo "#Set environment
#[PRODUCTION, STAGING, TESTING, DEVELOPMENT] 

SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'PRODUCTION'" > /path/to/.htaccess
```

Remember to replace `/path/to/` with the path to `.htaccess` and then copy the file using scp. This will replace the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. The problem is that the `.htaccess` file contains a lot of text besides the line that I need to change. The solution that you offered will erase everything else, correct?

Comment: Do you know the line number of the file which you want to modify?

Comment: Yes, it's 28th, which is `SetEnv KOHANA_ENV 'PRODUCTION'`

Comment: @Maximus: chaos' answer should work now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert just the 28th line, you can do:

```
sed '28s/DEVELOPMENT/PRODUCTION/' file
```

(combinable with -i option, of course)

If you want to avoid modifying a local file, you can do:

```
< /local/path/to/.htaccess sed '28s/DEVELOPMENT/PRODUCTION/' | ssh user@host "cat > /server/path/to/.htaccess"
```